# Change/filter text for no_password_reset error message

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling

## What I have:

1. I have a regular WordPress wp-login.php log-in page.
2. I've disabled the option for users to request password resets.
3. An error message is presented to users informing them that resets are disabled upon attempting reset.

## What I need:

I need to change/filter the text of the error message that reads "Password reset is not allowed for this user".

## My code:

The regular way filtering error messages that ordinarily works:

```
add_filter( 'wp_login_errors', 'override_incorrect_password_msg', 10, 2 );
function override_incorrect_password_msg( $errors, $redirect_to ) {
    if( isset( $errors->errors['incorrect_password'] ) ) {
        $errors->errors['incorrect_password'][0] = '<span>Please provide the <strong>correct password</strong>.</span>';
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

Transposing the above for the required message doesn't work:

```
add_filter( 'wp_login_errors', 'noreset_msg', 10, 2 );
function noreset_msg( $errors, $redirect_to ) {
    if( isset( $errors->errors['no_password_reset'] ) ) {
        $errors->errors['no_password_reset'][0] = '<span>Password reset is not allowed for this user.</span>';
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

## My question:

Why isn't this working considering I'm pretty sure I have [the correct filter](http://pt.wpseek.com/retrieve_password/)?

Comment: You link to the `retrieve_password` filter, yet you're hooking your function to the `wp_login_errors` filter. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @henrywright - I was hoping that `wp_login_errors` universally handled errors for both logging in and password resets. I tried hooking into `retrieve_password` but my code nonetheless took no effect. I can't work out in what manner the errors are being handled for disabled password resets.

Comment: Are you using WooCommerce?

Comment: @doublesharp - My theme is built to support WooCommerce but the plugin itself is currently deactivated as I develop the rest of the website.

Comment: Not sure about that... that string is only found in WooCommerce as far as I know.

Comment: Maybe double check to see if the code I posted in my answer works for you anyway?

Comment: My response is appended as a comment to your provided answer.

Answer (score 0):

The 'wp_login_errors' filter is not something which works when resetting the password.

You should use 'allow_password_reset' filter instead. You might have used a plugin or a piece of code to disable the password reset option. If you are seeing the default error message that means that code/plugin has returned 'false' Boolean value and then WordPress is throwing its default message. You can override this message by throwing a new WP error in following way - (Please note: When using the following code, you should remove the code/plugin using which you have disabled the password reset option. Following will disable the password reset option as well as throw a custom message) -

```
add_filter( 'allow_password_reset', 'noreset_msg', 99, 2 );

function noreset_msg($allow, $user_id){

   return new WP_Error('no_password_reset', __('Your custom message'));
}
```